# Laravel 5 storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried to upload an image file in a sub-folder but I didn't get the help from internet. In Laravel website they mentioned about create folder but not explaining about sub-folders. My purpose is I need to upload an image in to sub-folder. Eg: userdata/1/1.jpg.

I have tried some code which is given below.

```
public function store(ProfileimageRequest $request, $id)
    {
        User::findOrFail($id);
        $file      = $request->file('file'); 
        Storage::makeDirectory($id); //result is 1
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('local')->put($id.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file)); //result is 1.jpg
    }
```

The result of above code is creating folder "1" and image "1.jpg" but image is not creating inside the folder.

Comment: i think its a bit optimal to your app if you saved all photos in one folder but track them by making a record for each in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to specify that you want to the file to be uploaded into the folder. In the `put()` method add the folder's name with the file's name.

```
public function store(ProfileimageRequest $request, $id)
    {
        User::findOrFail($id);
        $file      = $request->file('file'); 
        Storage::makeDirectory($id); //result is 1
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('local')->put($id.'/'.$id.'.'.$extension, File::get($file)); 
    }
```

Let me know if this works out for you.